# Can the theory of multiverse explain dark matter?

Tags: gravity, universe, dark-matter

If there are many universes, they must have a gravity effect on each other. Since dark matter is measured through gravity, but we don't know the mass behind it, isn't it possible that it comes from another universe?

Comment: "If there are many universes, they must have a gravity effect on each other." Please give evidence for this assertion. The usual understanding of different universes is that things in other universes can have absolutely no effect on each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a speculative question, but I can answer it.

Dark matter has been observed in galaxies, and the distributions of dark matter in galaxies have also been measured. It seems clear that the matter is firmly in our universe - we just can't detect it with electromagnetic radiation.
*However, there are ideas (extremely speculative) that dark matter [is from a different spatial dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Mass_in_extra_dimensions). It sort of explains why gravity is so weak (it "leaks off" through the other dimension(s)). Note, though, that this highly, *highly* speculative.

There are ideas like this in string theory, too. Some say that we are trapped on a *[brane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology)*, a section of space-time with three spatial dimensions. However, there are one or more additional dimensions. All of these dimensions are known as the *bulk*. Gravity can "leak off" through these extra dimensions. Some theories take this to the extreme, and say that there exist many universes (of a certain number of dimensions each, but with less dimensions that those of the bulk) that are branes, just like ours. These have been considered the source of phenomena such as dark energy - in which case your scenario is within the realm of plausibility.

All of these ideas, however, are speculative and have no evidence in their favor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are very interesting theories in it I will read with pleasure!

Comment: @HDE226868, "Dark matter has been observed in galaxies.." I hadn't heard that.  Can you cite a source?

Comment: @TracyCramer [Here](http://astro.berkeley.edu/~mwhite/darkmatter/rotcurve.html), for example. Not to sound snarky (and I sincerely apologize if I do), but where else would we have observed it?

Comment: @HDE226868, I took your use of the word "observed" literally and thought there was some new discovery I hadn't heard about.

Comment: @TracyCramer Well, not to my knowledge. . . Although that doesn't mean much; I'm not incredibly up-to-date on experimental discoveries at the moment.

Comment: To clarify HDE's claims above. Dark matter has not, repeat not, been observed. It has been inferred. There is a big difference. The inference is due to observations of violations of Kepler's 3rd law in large structures like galaxies. For an analogy: say you are able to look up in the sky, and from the relative size and motion of airplanes you see, calculate their velocity. Then you see airplanes and calculate they have a speed of 10,000 mph. But that's impossible, according to current laws of motion, energy, and atmosphere. So you posit that some sort of cavitation (a vacuum) is produced in

Comment: front of airplanes, reducing friction enough to explain the excess speed. Yes, it could be true. But it's a conjecture, not an observed fact. And there's a problem; lots of $ and effort have sought dark matter particles, and nothing robust has been found.

Comment: If gravity was 'leaking' from our brane, wouldn't there also be gravity from other branes 'leaking' into ours?

Comment: @HowardMiller That is in fact exactly what HDE says: "that are branes, just like ours. These have been considered the source of phenomena such as dark energy"

Comment: @called2voyage Maybe one day we'll learn how to change the nature of small areas of spacetime.